# Android poor quality when resize Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, resize

I have a problem when I resize one image bitmap in my application, the image quality deteriorates.

My code for resize is as follows..

```
public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(newWidth, newHeight,
            Config.ARGB_8888);

    float ratioX = newWidth / (float) bm.getWidth();
    float ratioY = newHeight / (float) bm.getHeight();
    float middleX = newWidth / 2.0f;
    float middleY = newHeight / 2.0f;

    Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
    scaleMatrix.postScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    paint.setDither(true);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
    canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bm, middleX - bm.getWidth() / 2,
            middleY - bm.getHeight() / 2, paint);
    return scaledBitmap;
}
```

Any good solution for resize bitmap ¿?

Comment: refer this url http://android.okhelp.cz/resize-a-bitmap-image-android-example/ & http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2009/12/25/resizing-a-bitmap/

Comment: why are you not just using `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, newWidth, newHeight, true)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this Code,  I hope it will help you

```
    /***
 * This method is for aspect ratio means the image is set acc. to the aspect
 * ratio.
 * 
 * @param bmp
 *            bitmap passed
 * @param newWidth
 *            width you want to set for your image
 * @param newHeight
 *            hight you want to set for your image
 * @return bitmap
 */
public Bitmap resizeBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
    Log.i(TAG,
            "height = " + bmp.getHeight() + "\nwidth = " + bmp.getWidth());
    if (bmp.getHeight() > newHeight || bmp.getWidth() > newWidth) {
        int originalWidth = bmp.getWidth();
        int originalHeight = bmp.getHeight();
        Log.i("TAG", "originalWidth = " + originalWidth
                + "\noriginalHeight = " + originalHeight);
        float inSampleSize;
        if (originalWidth > originalHeight) {
            inSampleSize = (float) newWidth / originalWidth;
        } else {
            inSampleSize = (float) newHeight / originalHeight;
        }
        newWidth = Math.round(originalWidth * inSampleSize);
        newHeight = Math.round(originalHeight * inSampleSize);
        Log.i("", "newWidth = " + newWidth + "\nnewHeight = " + newHeight);
        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, newWidth, newHeight, true);
    } else {
        bitmap = bmp;
        Log.i("", "bitmapWidth = " + bitmap.getWidth()
                + "\nbitmapHeight = " + bitmap.getHeight());
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: I try this solution but the image quality is bad...I think that the proble is because I convert the bitmap to ByteArrayOutPutStream for paste in PDF Document..like this:  Bitmap bit1 = resizeBitmap(mBitmap, 100, 300);
   ByteArrayOutputStream streamDoc1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   bit1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, streamDoc1);
   byte[] docByte1 = streamDoc1.toByteArray();

   Image image = Image.getInstance(docByte1);